# Image within a div issues scss

Tags: css

I have an image within a div that is one of many that could be used in this component.  The idea is that if an image doesn't fit the div, then it will have black background on the left and right, otherwise if it fits, it will fill the container completely without showing the background.

If the image fills the div, it seems to have a little of the background peeking on the right and bottom even though it should in theory fit its container. `object fit:contain` seems to be the closest I can get so that this has black on the right and left of images that are smaller than the div and it almost has the desired effect on the images that fill other than this weird part of the background that peeks out.  If I use `object-fit:none`, it does remove the border on this one that fits the container, but it makes a box around smaller images rather than just black on the right and left.

I have tried adjusting the margin, object fit, position (absolute, etc.), fit and other things, but this border stays.  I have looked in [here](https://devhints.io/sass) and [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/10/object-fit-background-size-css/) for ideas on what else to try, but that weird border still seems to show up.
[image: problem image]

This is my SCSS:

```
.container {
    flex: 1;

    .image {
      // /* Maintain aspect ratio without resizing */
      height: auto;
      max-height: 310px;
      width: 100%;
      object-fit: contain;
      /* Cover the container without distortion */
      min-width: 250px;
      background-color: black;
      
    }
  }
```

When I see what the browser sees, I get this:

```
.v2-container .container image {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 310px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    min-width: 250px;
    background-color: #000000;
}
img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
img {
    border-style: none;
}
*, :after, :before {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

img {
    overflow-clip-margin: content-box;
    overflow: clip;
}
```

Comment: Is the rendered CSS what you intend? Does the browser developer tools show any unintended padding on the image?

Comment: I show there's no unintended padding or margins.  The intention is to have the image completely fill the container.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: I appreciate that you showed the SCSS, but that isn't what the browser sees. The browser's developer tools will show you what is actually being rendered. Just press F12. Sometimes we forget that there is some other styling applied to some element type, and it only shows up when we check what the browser says.

Comment: Thank you, I updated it.  There is some improvement where it looks as expected if I uncheck the :after, :before psuedoclasses that are coming in from the foundation styling being used.  I'm not too sure how to override those though.